# How to force Quick Parts to update in Word document?

Tags: quick-parts

I have a MS Word document which has a Quick Part in the header that displays a value from "Document Status" single line of text field. Everything works as expected while the document is being edited.

Here is where the trouble starts.
I have developed a workflow (using CSOM) which is run on that document. The workflow changes the value of the "Document Status" property from "Draft" to "Official" and then creates a PDF copy of the document. It seems that when the "Document Status" is changed by the workflow, that change is reflected in the Quick Part only when I open the document in MS Word, because the PDF copy keeps displaying "Draft" (and MS Word document displays "Official" when I open it).

Is there a way to force the Quick Part to update through code (preferably CSOM) without having to open the document in MS Word? I tried additional `.Update()` and `.CheckOut()` / `.CheckIn()` - none of which worked.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: No, sorry. I think Microsoft might  have given up on it :)